# automatic payments in installments?

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, auto-renew

We use CiviCRM for an educational program. Currently, parents enroll students in classes, and then have the option to pay automatically on a monthly basis through the use of a monthly membership on auto-renew. The issue is that we do not run programming in the summers, so each of these auto-renew memberships has to be manually shut off by us at the end of the school year.

Is there a way to set auto-renew to expire? Or alternately, is there a way to set up a yearly tuition/membership that is paid in monthly installments, and ends when the full amount has been paid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a contribution page, it is possible to set the 'recurring' to 'offer installments: "Give the user a choice of installments (e.g. donate every month for 6 months)? If not, recurring donations will continue indefinitely." That may be one place you could look at doing a minor customisation so that rather than 'offering' the number, you specify it and hide it.

Comment: Interesting! I will definitely look into that option. Are you able to explain more specifically how a customization would work in this case?

Comment: not technically but assume a bit of javascript could be used to force set that field and hide it. we have done similar in order to eg set 'auto renew' as defaulting to 'yes' rather than 'no' for memberships (for my own notes r10545)